# KL divergence and mixture of Gaussians

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, st.statistics, probability-distributions, gaussian

Do we have an exact formula to compute the KL divergence between 2 mixtures of Gaussians (i.e convex combinations of a finite number of Gaussian distributions)?

If not exactly known, are there good upperbounds that are known for this quantity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no closed form expression, for approximations see:

- [Lower and upper bounds for approximation of the Kullback-Leibler divergence between Gaussian mixture models](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/174055/files/durrieuThiranKelly_kldiv_icassp2012_R1.pdf) (2012)

> A lower and an upper bound for the Kullback-Leibler divergence between
>   two Gaussian mixtures are proposed. The mean of these bounds provides an
>   approximation to the KL divergence which is shown to be equivalent to
>   a previously proposed approximation in:

- [Approximating the Kullback Leibler Divergence Between Gaussian Mixture Models](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4249249_Approximating_the_Kullback_Leibler_Divergence_Between_Gaussian_Mixture_Models) (2007)

Comment: I looked into this paper quite a lot. How good do you think the result is? It seems to be quite loose an upperbound. As in when there is no mixture but just 2 Gaussians then this upperbound seems to be a additive error of dimension away from the true KL which is known in this case.

Comment: What is your conclusion regarding the tightness of this approximation? Were you able to find tighter bounds? This is the first paper that shows up in Google search.